# Беспрерывное воспроизведение видео в wpf

Tags: c#, .net, wpf

Есть задача - программа на c# wpf: 
воспроизводить несколько видео подряд/
делаю с помощью media element, однако при смене видео происходит моргание, которого быть не должно.
Моргание происходит при смене свойства source, программная пауза не поможет...

куда копать? как буферизовать видео в .net?

Comment: Сделать второй media element, который находится в скрытом состоянии. Пока первый близок к окончанию проигрывания во второй подгружаем нужное видео и в нужный момент стартуем воспроизведение и видимость у второго и выключаем видимость у первого.

Answer (score 1):

Проблему решил следующим образом:
2 элемента media
+ алгоритм поочередной смены источника видео для 1-го и 2-го видео, причем
+ использование событий on_media_ended

Comment: Решение - классика!